# How to get the program to find minimum

Tags: drop-down-menu

```
list = "\n==== Names and Distances ====\n"
firstName = input ("Enter next person's first name >")
while firstName > "":
    distance= float(input("Enter distance thrown: "))
    list = list + firstName + "." + str(distance) + "\n"
    firstName = input ("Enter next person's first name >")
    largest = max([distance])
    smallest = min([distance])
print (list)
print ("the longest distance is: " + str(largest))
print (smallest)
```

When I run the program it is giving me the same distance for maximum and minimum any ideas on how to get just minimum?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is python

`distance` is a float so `max([distance])` will be equal to `distance`

you can solve it in many ways

One easy way is to initialize largest to be a very small value and smallest to be a very large value and change these lines:

```
largest = max([distance])
smallest = min([distance])
```

to:

```
largest = max(largest,distance)
smallest = min(smallest,distance)
```